# Azure DevOps release deployment failing Disk Space Error

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have an app I am trying to deploy through azure's DevOps pipeline. I have successfully deployed apps before, and the first build of this app deployed fine. However all subsequent builds have been failing at the deployment step. They seem to be specifically failing at the "Deploy Azure App Service" step, generating a ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_DISK_SPACE error code.

The deployment terminal output shows the following errors:

```
Got connection details for Azure App Service:'MMOMarketTracker'
[command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='D:\a\r1\a\_MMMarketTracker\build\build.zip' -dest:contentPath='MMOMarketTracker',ComputerName='https://mmomarkettracker.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=MMOMarketTracker',UserName='$MMOMarketTracker',Password='***',AuthType='Basic' -enableRule:AppOffline -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -userAgent:VSTS_ba2ca09f-578d-4893-99ac-412c3f26fde5_release_1_9_9_1
2018-11-22T21:02:35.2302461Z Info: Using ID 'e7a243b1-97df-4ec2-b8d9-c679c2e35512' for connections to the remote server.
Info: Adding directory (MMOMarketTracker\s\.git\objects\15).
Error: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\3.4.16\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\toolrunner.js:568:30)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
[command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='D:\a\r1\a\_MMMarketTracker\build\build.zip' -dest:contentPath='MMOMarketTracker',ComputerName='https://mmomarkettracker.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=MMOMarketTracker',UserName='$MMOMarketTracker',Password='***',AuthType='Basic' -enableRule:AppOffline -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -userAgent:VSTS_ba2ca09f-578d-4893-99ac-412c3f26fde5_release_1_9_9_1
Info: Using ID '201db2e8-ee9f-4e39-9a29-2187cb7056bd' for connections to the remote server.
Info: Adding directory (MMOMarketTracker\s\.git\objects\15).
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[error]Error Code: ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_DISK_SPACE
More Information: Web Deploy detected insufficient space on disk.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_DISK_SPACE.
Error: The error code was 0x80070070.
Error: There is not enough space on the disk.

at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirectoryEx.CreateDirectory(String path)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.CreateDirectory(String fullPath, DeploymentObject source)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
Error count: 1.

##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295
```

The first error seems to be caused by the remote server failing to add a git object. This error will usually occur 2-3 times each deployment, and will result in the "Retrying to to deploy the package" message shown.

The second error will happen once and will end the deployment. I have been to the link the error recommends and there is no help section for this type of error. 
I downloaded the build file and it is only 49.3 MB large, and the Microsoft servers have a 10GB size for deployments. I am running on a hosted build agent, not a private one.

Other questions I found online similar to this are mostly unanswered. Some have been updated later to say the deployment started working for seemingly no reason.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please cut and paste the error text and update the question with it?  Those images are hard to read - and we cannot select/copy any of the text.  Also is this a hosted build agent, or a private one?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've updated the question. I'm running on a hosted build agent.

Comment: This might get you looking in the right direction: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/puneetgupta/2017/06/06/azure-app-service-what-is-taking-my-disk-space-for-my-azure-web-app/

Comment: I deleted some old apps and retried the deploy and it worked. Weird that I couldn't find that article when I searched msdn myself, it helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @BrendanGreen you could provide you comment as answer,so that Jonathan can accept it

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who gets the same problem, I basically had too many other apps taking up space on my azure account. The article Brendan Green linked explains this. 
(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/puneetgupta/2017/06/06/azure-app-service-what-is-taking-my-disk-space-for-my-azure-web-app/)

By going to the Quotas page on any of your azure apps (in the azure portal) you can see how much space you have left.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you're out of staging slots in your pricing tier. So, a workout solution is to upgrade your pricing tier to acquire more staging slots.

The staging slots are used for testing and deployments before swapping them into production and it does not associate with your file system disk space.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to reclaim disk space by triggering the build agent cleanup process.

[image]